# socket keepalive works with xp but not with windows 7 c#

Tags: c#, sockets, connection, disconnect

I have a strange problem:
I have a list of TcpClients that I need to be notified when one of them disconnects.
When each of them is initialized I set their socket to keepalive (setsocketoption, and iocontrol) and there does not seem to be any problem with it (no exceptions).

Than I have a seperated thread that checks each TcpClient the Connected property of their Socket.
The problem is that even when the ip is no longer connected (for example I disconnect the network cable) the boolean is still true (connected).
I tried changing the code to (socket.available == true) && socket.poll(1, socketMode.selectread) without any change.

A very important remark:
The same exact code works with win Xp (the Connected property is false when there is no connection) but does not work with win7 and there are no exceptions.

I am running the program as administrator and I disabled the firewall.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `Connected` boolean is true until either a Send or Receive operation fails. This is the nature of TCP/IP. So for example if you had a connected socket from computer A to B, then unplugged the network cable on computer B, computer A wouldn't report the socket is disconnected until the next time you try to send some data.

I suggest implementing some kind of ping/pong mechanism that you send every n interval such as 5 seconds to see if the other end is still alive or not.

I don't know why your tests show it's different on XP and windows 7, I would have thought there is no difference. Perhaps by chance on XP you were sending some data just after you unplugged the cable which triggered `Connected` to be set to false?